# unable to call SSIS package with OData Source connection manager using .bat file

Tags: batch-file, ssis-2012

Unable to call SSIS package with  OData Source connection manager using .bat file

Receiving below error:
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Started:  9:14:45 AM
Error: 2016-01-16 09:14:46.80
   Code: 0xC0014005
   Source: Test_Package
   Description: The connection type "ODATA" specified for connection manager "OData Source" is not recognized as a valid connection manager type. This error is returned when an attempt is made to create a connection manager for an unknown connection type. Check the spelling in the connection type name.
End Error
Error: 2016-01-16 09:14:46.80
   Code: 0xC0010018 
   Source: Test_Package
   Description: Error loading value "
End Error
Could not load package "F:\New Packages\Sharepoint\Test_Package.dtsx" because of error 0xC0010014.
Description: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
Source: Test_Package
Started:  9:14:45 AM
Finished: 9:14:46 AM
Elapsed:  1.638 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue 30 seconds ago in a Dev Server.

My issue was related to the fact that i had installed the 32Bit OData Source (ODataSourceForSQLServer2012-x86) hence was able to create and run the package from visual studio.

However, once released on the SSIS server, the 64Bit run-time was used hence the above error. The error disappeared as soon as i installed the 64Bit OData Source package (ODataSourceForSQLServer2012-amd64).

I guess one might forget that the OData Source packages (both versions eventually) must be installed in the production server for a SSIS package that uses OData source to work.